# Is there a text-shadow for Divs?

Tags: css

i was wondering if there is something like text-shadow for DIVs, we all know that text-shadow is only for dropping a shadow to the text, but i want a shadow for a complete DIV.

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using text-shadow you are using CSS3, so try the [box-shadow property](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/).

Comment: Thanks so much , that's what i went, i'm using CSS3

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it with css3 on the newer browsers and filters with IE.  I read about it in this [extremely good article](http://www.phpied.com/css-performance-ui-with-fewer-images/) a while back. Basically you can take the following CSS and apply it to a div and it should work with FF, Safari, Chrome, Opera, IE5.5 and up.

```
.module {
  /* offset left, top, thickness, color with alpha */
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* IE */
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color='gray');
  /* slightly different syntax for IE8 */
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.dropshadow(OffX=5, OffY=5, Color='gray')";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [border-image](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/)

```
border-image: url(shadow.png);
```

CSS3 Only though

Answer (score 0):

You can use images to get the shadow effects for divs. [Alist apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssdropshadows/) has nice articles on it.